# Custom Post Type / Taxonomy not displaying archive

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I am trying to use the Atreas Theme: https://wordpress.org/themes/antreas/

This is the site I am working on: https://sandbox.paediatricphysiotherapyassociates.com/

All I want is an archive page for my Team Members to display them all in one spot. 
I tried adding:
`'has_archive'       => true'`
to the plugin php files directly "cpost-team.php" but I can't for the life of me find the url for the archive page for Team Members. Either that or I'm missing something else. This is the direct code for this "Custom Posts" (aka Team Members) plugin:

```
<?php

//Define team post type
add_action( 'init', 'cpo_cpost_team' );
function cpo_cpost_team() {
   $show_ui = false;
   if ( defined( 'CPOTHEME_USE_TEAM' ) || cpo_get_option( 'display_team' ) ) {
       $show_ui = true;
   }
   $labels = array(
       'name'               => __( 'Team Members', 'cpo-companion' ),
       'singular_name'      => __( 'Team Member', 'cpo-companion' ),
       'add_new'            => __( 'Add Team Member', 'cpo-companion' ),
       'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Team Member', 'cpo-companion' ),
       'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Team Member', 'cpo-companion' ),
       'new_item'           => __( 'New Team Member', 'cpo-companion' ),
       'view_item'          => __( 'View Team Member', 'cpo-companion' ),
       'search_items'       => __( 'Search Team Members', 'cpo-companion' ),
       'not_found'          => __( 'No team members found.', 'cpo-companion' ),
       'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No team members found in the trash.', 'cpo-companion' ),
       'parent_item_colon'  => '',
   );

   $member_slug = cpo_get_option( 'slug_team_member' );
   if ( '' == $member_slug ) {
       $member_slug = 'cpo_team';
   }

   $fields = array(
       'labels'              => $labels,
       'public'              => true,
       'publicly_queryable'  => true,
       'exclude_from_search' => true,
       'show_ui'             => $show_ui,
       'query_var'           => true,
       'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => apply_filters( 'cpotheme_slug_team_member', $member_slug ) ),
       'capability_type'     => 'page',
       'hierarchical'        => false,
       'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-universal-access',
       'menu_position'       => null,
       'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes' ),
   );

   register_post_type( 'cpo_team', $fields );

}


//Define admin columns in team post type
add_filter( 'manage_edit-cpo_team_columns', 'cpo_cpost_team_columns' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'cpo_cpost_team_columns' ) ) {
   function cpo_cpost_team_columns( $columns ) {
       $columns = array(
           'cb'             => '<input type="checkbox" />',
           'ctct-image'     => __( 'Image', 'cpo-companion' ),
           'title'          => __( 'Title', 'cpo-companion' ),
           'ctct-team-cats' => __( 'Groups', 'cpo-companion' ),
           'date'           => __( 'Date', 'cpo-companion' ),
           'author'         => __( 'Author', 'cpo-companion' ),
       );
       return $columns;
   }
}

//Define team category taxonomy
add_action( 'init', 'cpo_tax_teamcategory' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'cpo_tax_teamcategory' ) ) {
   function cpo_tax_teamcategory() {
       $labels = array(
           'name'               => __( 'Member Groups', 'cpo-companion' ),
           'singular_name'      => __( 'Member Group', 'cpo-companion' ),
           'add_new'            => __( 'New Member Group', 'cpo-companion' ),
           'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add Member Group', 'cpo-companion' ),
           'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Member Group', 'cpo-companion' ),
           'new_item'           => __( 'New Member Group', 'cpo-companion' ),
           'view_item'          => __( 'View Member Group', 'cpo-companion' ),
           'search_items'       => __( 'Search Member Groups', 'cpo-companion' ),
           'not_found'          => __( 'No member groups were found.', 'cpo-companion' ),
           'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No member groups were found in the trash.', 'cpo-companion' ),
           'parent_item_colon'  => '',
       );

       $slug = cpo_get_option( 'slug_team_category' );
       if ( '' == $slug ) {
           $slug = 'team-group';
       }
       $fields = array(
           'labels'            => $labels,
           'public'            => true,
           'show_ui'           => true,
           'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
           'show_tagcloud'     => false,
           'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => apply_filters( 'cpotheme_slug_team_category', $slug ) ),
           'hierarchical'      => true,
       );

       register_taxonomy( 'cpo_team_category', 'cpo_team', $fields );
   }
}
```

Also based on the code what should the url outcome be? I assumed it should be on: https://sandbox.paediatricphysiotherapyassociates.com/cpo_team/

Additionally my custom taxonomy for team members (groups) is not displaying posts that fall under the given group: https://sandbox.paediatricphysiotherapyassociates.com/?cpo_team_category=ba
[image]

Sorry I'm not great with php. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

A generous soul helped me from a different community. Turns out it was a very simple fix: [image]

**Still looking for help for the custom taxonomy for team members (groups) is not displaying posts that fall under the given group:** https://sandbox.paediatricphysiotherapyassociates.com/?cpo_team_category=ba